# How to optimize/replace cursor in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, database-cursor

I am working with a cursor and was wondering if this can be done away with and optimized?

Comment: It almost certainly can, but I'm not convinced that this code does what you want to do, or in fact does anything useful. @ActiveCount will always be non-zero, since you do an inner join on StudentID in your cursors select statement.

Comment: Makes no sense to me.  If  at ActiveStudent = 0 then there is nothing in student so the main query returns nothing. You could shorten it to select  at NumberCreations = 0

Comment: The question is unclear. From what I'm seeing here, this code is not clear, as we have no context for the table structures involved. What is the end goal in plain language?

Comment: I particular like the `fetch into @ParentId` and then not using the value at all.  Why bother having a cursor?

Comment: Yes, I noticed that too, @Gordon.

Comment: The cursor is currently just used to get the number of Creations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT s.StudentId, COUNT(*) AS CreationCount 
FROM Student s
INNER JOIN CreationHist c
    ON c.StudentId = s.StudentId
WHERE c.CreateDate = '05/02/2011'
GROUP BY s.StudentId
```